# Why does the router redirect to another route when a refresh happens?

Tags: ember.js

I have a survey application built using Ember JS, Firebase and a Torii Adapter for authentication and session management. I'm trying to understand the behavior of a specific route (called the 'takesurvey' route) when it is refreshed.

The related code from the router map (router.js) is given below:

```
this.route('user', function() {
    this.route('surveys');
    //the code below works but on refresh, 
    //nests the takesurvey page under user
    this.route('takesurvey', {path: ':survey_id', resetNamespace: true}); 
  });
   //alternatively, uncommenting the line below redirects to user.surveys on refresh of page
   //this.route('takesurvey', {path: ':survey_id'});
```

Here's the issue with two scenarios (also described as comments in the code above):

**Scenario 1: The takesurvey page is kept as a stand-alone route**

In this case the take survey page loads fine when a user navigates to `http://<application name> /survey_id`. But on refresh of the page, it takes the user back to the `user/surveys` page.

**Scenario 2: The takesurvey route is nested underneath the user route.**

In this case, when the user navigates to `http://<application name> /user/survey_id`, the survey loads fine and the refresh also works as expected.

So my question is, *why* does this happen?

Ideally, based on current requirements, I'd like to keep the takesurvey page as a standalone route and when a user clicks on refresh on that takesurvey page, it should continue to be there on that same page and not redirect him to the user/surveys page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are *overriding* the path for the `takesurvey` route.

Change your router to look like the following and let me know if that works for you:

```
this.route('user', function() {
  this.route('surveys');
  this.route('takesurvey', {path: 'takesurvey/:survey_id', resetNamespace: true}); 
});
```